# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'css' in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Scraping website :  http://quotes.toscrape.com

I am using Scrapy 2.3.0.

I am trying to scrape all the quotes along with its author and its tags the from the above website.

Can someone please explain to me why this code is giving

```
Error :
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'css'
```

at line :

```
author = quote.css('.author::text').extract()
```

[image: cmd]

I am learning to use scrapy and I am stuck at this.
import scrapy

```
class QuotesSpider( scrapy.Spider ):
    name = "crawler"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/'
        ]

    def parse( self, response ):

        all_quotes = response.css(".quote")

        for quote in all_quotes:

            quote = quote.css('text::text').extract()
            author = quote.css('.author::text').extract()
            tags = quote.css('.tags::text').extract()
        
            yield {
                'quote': quote,
                'author' : author,
                'tags' : tags
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that the variable `quote` refers to a list when Python executes the line that is giving you the error (and the inbuilt list data type has no attribute called "css").

I would suggest debugging your code (if you know how to do that). That should provide you with the insights as to what is the exact problem.

If you are not comfortable with debugging, then comment out everything in the `for` loop except the line with `quote = quote.css('text::text').extract()` and add a `print(quote)` to see what is the exact structure of the list that your variable `quote` is referring to.

PS: I would suggest using better variable names (and not reassign `quote` in the `for` loop as you have) so as to prevent any confusion. Additionally, I would strongly recommend you to learn how to debug (if you do not know how to do that already) as it is really helpful.